# Extracting coefficients from frailty survival model with sparse=T

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am fitting a survival model in R with time-dependent covariates and using frailty.gaussian() for some of the variables.

An example call is

```
coxph1 <- coxph(Surv(tstart,tstop,dstatus)~x+frailty.gaussian(y,sparse=T),data=data)
```

where y is a factor variable with many levels. I would like to extract the random effect blups (or any estimate) from y. Is there a good way to do this? Note that I am sticking with the survival package because it allows for the fitting of time-dependent covariates. Would be happy to move to another frailty package as long as it can deal with those.

Thanks!

Comment: is there a built in data set you'd like us to use that works with this so that we can all work off of the same reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example where I have no problem extracting the frailty estimates..

```
    library(survival)
    data(rats)
    coxph1 <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~rx+frailty.gaussian(litter,sparse=T),data=rats)
    hist(coxph1$frail)
```